# Need help to insert a pdf image and table to a beamer (latex) presentation

Tags: tables, beamer, graphics

I am creating a beamer (latex) presentation, but I have some problems inserting images and tables,I have obtained this images and tables from R, with "savepdf" and "stargazer" respectively.

I need to insert a pdf image, which contains some plots, but what a I get is a slide with juts some part of the pdf image, I dont know how to do in order to have the entire image in the slide. This is my code:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{hyperref,float}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{standalone}

\usetheme{CambridgeUS}

\begin{figure}[htbp]
\caption{Titulo del grafico}
\label{grafico_1}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=1\textwidth]{imagen_1.pdf}
\end{figure}
```

And the same problem happens with tables, I just get some part of it, and I dont know to have the entire table into the slide. This is my code:

```
\begin{table}[!htbp] \centering 
\caption{Estadísticos principales} 
\label{estadisticos} 
\begin{tabular}{@{\extracolsep{5pt}}lccccccc} 
\\[-1.8ex]\hline 
\hline \\[-1.8ex] 
Statistic & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Mean} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{St. Dev.} & 
\multicolumn{1}{c}{Min} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Pctl(25)} & 
\multicolumn{1}{c}{Median} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Pctl(75)} & 
\multicolumn{1}{c}{Max} \\ 
\hline \\[-1.8ex] 
1M & 1.560 & 1.914 & 0.103 & 0.238 & 0.400 & 2.877 & 5.866 \\ 
3M & 1.737 & 1.888 & 0.198 & 0.354 & 0.654 & 3.052 & 5.792 \\ 
6M & 1.917 & 1.813 & 0.281 & 0.561 & 0.938 & 3.290 & 5.692 \\ 
9M & 2.024 & 1.731 & 0.319 & 0.716 & 1.152 & 3.377 & 5.604 \\ 
12M & 2.134 & 1.660 & 0.455 & 0.918 & 1.279 & 3.556 & 5.614 \\ 
24M & 1.937 & 1.727 & 0.355 & 0.649 & 1.023 & 3.389 & 5.676 \\ 
36M & 2.176 & 1.631 & 0.430 & 0.962 & 1.369 & 3.704 & 5.663 \\ 
48M & 2.412 & 1.546 & 0.565 & 1.215 & 1.753 & 3.943 & 5.679 \\ 
60M & 2.627 & 1.470 & 0.753 & 1.502 & 1.971 & 4.098 & 5.697 \\ 
72M & 2.801 & 1.408 & 0.961 & 1.713 & 2.165 & 4.197 & 5.712 \\ 
84M & 2.978 & 1.351 & 1.066 & 1.890 & 2.455 & 4.279 & 5.727 \\ 
96M & 3.092 & 1.316 & 1.128 & 2.003 & 2.661 & 4.361 & 5.742 \\ 
108M & 3.209 & 1.283 & 1.190 & 2.122 & 2.848 & 4.445 & 5.756 \\ 
120M & 3.329 & 1.251 & 1.253 & 2.236 & 3.038 & 4.531 & 5.781 \\ 
\hline \\[-1.8ex] 
\end{tabular} 
\end{table}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Without having excess to your image, my best guess is that you need to make the image smaller, e.g. `\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{imagen_1.pdf}` or some other value

Comment: And for the table, use a smaller font size. Try with something like `\scriptsize`

Comment: If the above comments do not help, please make a compilable [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your images don't fit on the slide, reduce their size by changing `width=1\textwidth` to something smaller. I don't have your images, so I can only guess.

To reduce the size of your tables, choose a smaller font size or reduze the amount of information you show on a single slide.

Some other comments:

- you don't need `\usepackage{graphicx}` or `\usepackage{hyperref}` with beamer, as beamer already provied these functionalities
- the `float` package does not make much sense in a documentclass without floats
- floating specifier, such as `[htbp]`, don't make sense in beamer
- no need for `\centering`, beamer automatically centres figures and tables
- I suggest to use the `booktabs` package to get a nicer spacing in your table
- all these `\multicolumn` with span only a single column don't make much sense

---

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\usetheme{CambridgeUS}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
    \begin{figure}
        \caption{Titulo del grafico}
        \label{grafico_1}
        \includegraphics[width=.5\textwidth]{example-image}
    \end{figure}
\end{frame}


\begin{frame}
    \begin{table} 
        \caption{Estadísticos principales} 
        \label{estadisticos} 
        \small
        \begin{tabular}{lccccccc}
            \toprule
            Statistic & Mean & St. Dev. & Min & Pctl(25) & Median & Pctl(75) & Max \\ 
            \midrule 
            1M & 1.560 & 1.914 & 0.103 & 0.238 & 0.400 & 2.877 & 5.866 \\ 
            3M & 1.737 & 1.888 & 0.198 & 0.354 & 0.654 & 3.052 & 5.792 \\ 
            6M & 1.917 & 1.813 & 0.281 & 0.561 & 0.938 & 3.290 & 5.692 \\ 
            9M & 2.024 & 1.731 & 0.319 & 0.716 & 1.152 & 3.377 & 5.604 \\ 
            12M & 2.134 & 1.660 & 0.455 & 0.918 & 1.279 & 3.556 & 5.614 \\ 
            24M & 1.937 & 1.727 & 0.355 & 0.649 & 1.023 & 3.389 & 5.676 \\ 
            36M & 2.176 & 1.631 & 0.430 & 0.962 & 1.369 & 3.704 & 5.663 \\ 
            48M & 2.412 & 1.546 & 0.565 & 1.215 & 1.753 & 3.943 & 5.679 \\ 
            60M & 2.627 & 1.470 & 0.753 & 1.502 & 1.971 & 4.098 & 5.697 \\ 
            72M & 2.801 & 1.408 & 0.961 & 1.713 & 2.165 & 4.197 & 5.712 \\ 
            84M & 2.978 & 1.351 & 1.066 & 1.890 & 2.455 & 4.279 & 5.727 \\ 
            96M & 3.092 & 1.316 & 1.128 & 2.003 & 2.661 & 4.361 & 5.742 \\ 
            108M & 3.209 & 1.283 & 1.190 & 2.122 & 2.848 & 4.445 & 5.756 \\ 
            120M & 3.329 & 1.251 & 1.253 & 2.236 & 3.038 & 4.531 & 5.781 \\ 
            \bottomrule
        \end{tabular} 
    \end{table} 
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I don't know a `boobtabs` package :)